# Parse::RecDescent parse sub name

Tags: perl, grammar, parser-generator, parse-recdescent

I use module Parse::RecDescent
and try to build grammar to catch perl sub name
why in my code
https://gist.github.com/1595532

not work gramma
    get_sub: 
           NOWORD TEST NOWORD

on '>test1$' ? (variabble  $perl_code1 )

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Parse::RecDescent;

my $perl_code1  = q{my >test1$ string3 = $object->oldSub(6,7);};
my $perl_code2  = q{test1$ string3 = $object->oldSub(6,7);};
my $perl_code3  = q{my test1$ string3 = $object->oldSub(6,7);};
my @perl_lines  = ( $perl_code1, $perl_code2, $perl_code3 );
my $var         = 'test1';
my $sub_grammar = q{

    get_sub: 
           NOWORD TEST NOWORD
               {print $item[2]}      
           |TEST NOWORD
              {print $item[1]}     

    get_sub2: 
           WORD TEST NOWORD
               {print $item[2]}      
           |TEST NOWORD
              {print $item[1]}     

    WORD: 
        /\w+/    
    NOWORD: 
        /\W+/            
    TEST: 
        /} . $var . q{/
    };
my $sub_parse = new Parse::RecDescent($sub_grammar);
say 'example1:';

for my $string1 (@perl_lines) {
    say "Valid sub:$string1\n" if $sub_parse->get_sub($string1);
}

say 'example2:';
for my $string2 (@perl_lines) {
    say " Valid sub:$string2\n" if $sub_parse->get_sub2($string2);
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to parse Perl code, you want [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI), not Parse::RecDescent.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$perl_code1` starts with string `my`, which is not matched by the rule. You would need something like following in the grammar:

```
get_sub:
       WORD NOWORD TEST NOWORD
           ...
```